# CSS Grid changes track size when nested grid changes size

Tags: css, css-grid

In the snippet below, I have 5 cells named `a` through `e`. `a` and `b` should be side by side and as tall as possible with a fixed width. `c` should be below them, shrinking its height as much as possible and matching the width of `a` and `b` combined. `d` and `e` should be on the right, stacked with `d` on top, taking all available width with `e` having a fixed height and letting `d` take up as much height as possible.

I do not want the heights of `c` and `e` to be at all related. Thus, I have placed `d` and `e` in a nested grid (brilliantly named `de`). I expect that when I set the height of `e` to some value, it should become that height, and `d` should shrink or grow as needed, and everything else should stay the same. However, when I change the height of `e`, `c` also changes its height.

Why in the world is my nested grid effecting its parent, and how to I prevent it?

Here is the snippet, and [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TrevinAvery/jrtnp2gc/27/) just in case. You can change the height of `e` by adjusting the value if the input.

```js
let e = document.getElementById('e')
let heightInput = document.querySelector('#controls input')
heightInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
 e.style.height = heightInput.value + 'px'
})
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#controls {
  height: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#grid {
  background: orange;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 35px);
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto min-content;
  grid-template-areas:
    'a b de'
    'c c de';
}

#a {
  background: red;
  
  grid-area: a;
  width: 30px;
}

#b {
  background: blue;
  
  grid-area: b;
  width: 30px;
}

#c {
  background: green;
  
  grid-area: c;
}

#de {
  background: purple;
  
  grid-area: de;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto min-content;
  grid-template-areas:
    'd'
    'e';
}

#d {
  background: grey;
  
  grid-area: d;
}

#e {
  background: yellow;
  
  grid-area: e;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="controls">
    Set height of e in px <input type="number" value="30" />
  </div>
  <div id="grid">
    <div id="a">a</div>
    <div id="b">b</div>
    <div id="c">c</div>
    <div id="de">
      <div id="d">d</div>
      <div id="e">e</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I don't have an accurate explanation but this is due to the computation of `min-content`. Instead of it you can use the combination of `1fr` and `auto`

```js
let e = document.getElementById('e')
let heightInput = document.querySelector('#controls input')
heightInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
 e.style.height = heightInput.value + 'px'
})
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#controls {
  height: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#grid {
  background: orange;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 35px);
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto; /* updated this */
  grid-template-areas:
    'a b de'
    'c c de';
}

#a {
  background: red;
  
  grid-area: a;
  width: 30px;
}

#b {
  background: blue;
  
  grid-area: b;
  width: 30px;
}

#c {
  background: green;
  
  grid-area: c;
}

#de {
  background: purple;
  
  grid-area: de;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;  /* updated this too but not mandatory */
  grid-template-areas:
    'd'
    'e';
}

#d {
  background: grey;
  
  grid-area: d;
}

#e {
  background: yellow;
  
  grid-area: e;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="controls">
    Set height of e in px <input type="number" value="30" />
  </div>
  <div id="grid">
    <div id="a">a</div>
    <div id="b">b</div>
    <div id="c">c</div>
    <div id="de">
      <div id="d">d</div>
      <div id="e">e</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This did solve the problem, however, I would love to understand why `min-content` doesn't work how I would expect it to.